# With Razer BlackWidow, can you control which keys are backlit?

Tags: keyboard

With Razer BlackWidow, can you control which keys are backlit or is it all keys or no keys are lit?

Comment: Hey Matt. I've removed the "bonus" question about what other keyboards could do this, since shopping questions are off topic and leaving it in would probably have gotten the whole question closed.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more suitable for SuperUser than here on Arqade?

Comment: I actually debated this myself but since they are gaming keyboards, I opted for Arqade.

Comment: The website says "individually lit keys" which would make you think you could set which ones are lit, but I'm not sure how. Is there anything in the manual?

Comment: Are you talking about the BlackWidow Ultimate?  I don't think the "regular" BlackWidow is backlit...

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

It's all keys or no keys.  With levels of brightness.

#### Longer (warranty voiding) answer:

There is no way to customize the brightness of keys individually... **Unless** you want to mod your keyboard.

As advertised, each key is lit individually meaning there is at least one LED per key.  However, every single one of these LEDs is connected to the same controller, which makes them all do the same thing at the same time.

In order to have individually customizable key brightness you will need to take your keyboard apart, solder things, rewire the LEDs, possibly setup your own controller for each individual key, make sure everything fits, and eventually put everything back together...  [cocasdaneve](http://cocasdaneve.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/custom-led-color-and-brightness-on-a-razer-blackwidow-ultimate/) has great instructions for modding the BlackWidow and chart/explanation of how the LEDs are wired.
This mod does not make each key unique, it is, however, a great place to get started.

<sub>There are very few keyboards I can think of off the top of my head that have keys that are individually customizable; However, if you are after complete customization and have very deep pockets, check out the [Optimus](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/optimus/) line of keyboards.</sub>

Comment: http://www.corsair.com/k70 is backlit and has indivudially customizable keys. although the brightness is the same for every key